# Portfolio sd, covariance over different time periods

Tags: standard-deviation, covariance, time-series

So we are trying to forecasted portfolio return and deviation of a historic set of investments, we have different lengths of data for different investments. My boss calculated the covariance using the all the time periods the two shared, not only time periods available for all data.

I think this could cause an issue, can any one confirm this?

Comment: How can you calculate covariance otherwise? You need to select a period for which two series are available... Or you're trying to calculate the sample covariance matrix? In this case if you don't restrict periods, your matrix is not going to be positive semi definite which may cause issues as well...

Comment: Yes we are building the sample covariance matrix, and I know it is not positive semi definite, but what kind of issues will this cause. Would it cause the calculation of portfolio variance (transpose(weights)*matrix*weights) to be inaccurate?

Comment: It will cause problems in any procedure which requires a valid var-covar matrix (simple example - constructing "efficient frontier"). On the other hand, If the restricted sample is really short, your estimates will be inaccurate (so, you may want to calculate pairwise covariances using the entire sample and fix the resulting cov matrix later). However, there is another consideration: practically, correlations between financial instruments (e.g. securities, ETFs) are changing over time. In this case, it's better to restrict the length of the sample...

Comment: We are dealing with real estate returns broken up by region and type (office, apartment, retail, warehouse) so I dont think the correlations will change as much. How would you go about fixing the resulting cov matrix after getting the pairwise data?

Comment: http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1969689